# iOS : NSString file path to NSURL

Tags: iphone, ios

I have this :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/myusername/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/5ABF1395-4A80-46C0-BD4A-419ED98CE367/Documents/DBV/v.m4v"];
```

Then I launch movieViewController but it always crashes.. This code doesn't work on the iPhone simulator neither on the device... How can I fix it ?

EDIT :
Before to write file path by hand, I used the correct way to select a folder.

```
[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]
```

Then i got this log:

> file://localhost/Users/myusername/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulat‌​or/4.2/Applications/5ABF1395-4A80-46C0-BD4A-419ED98CE367/Documents/DBV/v.m4v

Then I thought it was because of spaces in folder name , so i decided to write the full path by hand for debugging (replacing each %20 by space)

EDIT 2 : Notice : I'm trying to access a dynamically created file in Documents folder, not a file from my bundle.

Comment: Maybe you need to use the right path.

Comment: I've already checked it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Which part ? I logged this from that code :
#define DOCUMENTS_DIRECTORY [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]
//...
NSString *path = [DOCUMENTS_DIRECTORY stringByAppendingString:@"/DBV/v.mp4"]; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

Comment: First off, you should never hard-code a path as you did in your example.  If you're really using some sort of dynamic path resolution you should post that instead.  Next, it's not clear whether you're accessing a dynamically created file (which would be in Documents) or a resource (which you should access from NSBundle).  Which is it?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. To make it clear , i'm trying to access a dynamically created file.

Comment: "Then I launch movieViewController but it always crashes." can you post your crash log/Reported error?

Comment: Actually there is no reported error, just crash... If I load a video from my bundle , movieViewController works...
Last log before crash (from iPhone device) :
STRING path : /var/mobile/Applications/54DF8BCD-8943-4B71-B0FF-8891121882BA/Documents/DBV/v.m4v

URL PATH file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/54DF8BCD-8943-4B71-B0FF-8891121882BA/Documents/DBV/v.m4v

Comment: OMG... I found the bug... At some point in the code I released a NSURL object which wasn't allocated with alloc/init methods... sorry everybody, i am going to bed.

Answer (score 2):

For files in documents, you should be getting the path from NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains.

```
//get list of document directories in sandbox 
NSArray *documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

//get one and only document directory from that list
NSString *documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex: 0];
```

Then you append the file name to that.

Comment: I forgot to mention that point but this is what i did. Then i got this log: file://localhost/Users/myusername/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/4.2/Applications/5ABF1395-4A80-46C0-BD4A-419ED98CE367/Documents/DBV/v.m4v
Then I thought it was because of spaces in folder name , so i decided to write the full path by hand (replacing each %20 by space)

Comment: You should not hardcode document directory paths. They will change at run time depending on where they are installed.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip. I thought the path was always the same when i run the app with the simulator.

Comment: Sorry but this didn't fix my problem ;(